# PHP - How to know the newest array inside an array object?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get data from an object that arrives as json, I transform it into an array of objects and look for the amount of array within a value. With that, I need to know which is the newest array within this array.

Example:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [canalAtendimento] => URA
                    [IdentificadorParceiroNegocio] => 
                    [IdentificadorInstalacao] => 7008000000
                    [Ani] => 21981737137
                    [DataInicio] => 
                    [HoraInicio] => 
                    [DataFim] => 04/05/2021
                    [HoraFim] => 09:42:25
                    [Dnis] => 
                    [MenuAtend] => 
                    [DocCliente] => 
                    [EnderecoVocalizado] => 
                    [Protocolo] => 
                    [GuidProtocolo] => 
                    [IdentificacaoNotaServico] => 
                    [Funcionalidade] => 
                    [Descricao] => 
                    [Usuario] => 
                    [NsDetails] => 
                    [created] => 04/05/2021 09:39:15
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [canalAtendimento] => URA
                    [IdentificadorParceiroNegocio] => 
                    [IdentificadorInstalacao] => 7008000000
                    [Ani] => 21981737137
                    [DataInicio] => 04/05/2021
                    [HoraInicio] => 09:43:00
                    [DataFim] => 04/05/2021
                    [HoraFim] => 09:45:14
                    [Dnis] => 
                    [MenuAtend] => 
                    [DocCliente] => 
                    [EnderecoVocalizado] => 
                    [Protocolo] => 
                    [GuidProtocolo] => 
                    [IdentificacaoNotaServico] => 
                    [Funcionalidade] => 
                    [Descricao] => 
                    [Usuario] => 
                    [NsDetails] => 
                    [created] => 04/05/2021 09:42:01
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [canalAtendimento] => URA
                    [IdentificadorParceiroNegocio] => 
                    [IdentificadorInstalacao] => 7008000000
                    [Ani] => 21981737137
                    [DataInicio] => 04/05/2021
                    [HoraInicio] => 10:15:51
                    [DataFim] => 04/05/2021
                    [HoraFim] => 10:16:25
                    [Dnis] => 
                    [MenuAtend] => 
                    [DocCliente] => 
                    [EnderecoVocalizado] => 
                    [Protocolo] => 
                    [GuidProtocolo] => 
                    [IdentificacaoNotaServico] => 
                    [Funcionalidade] => 
                    [Descricao] => 
                    [Usuario] => 
                    [NsDetails] => 
                    [created] => 04/05/2021 10:13:12
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [canalAtendimento] => URA
                    [IdentificadorParceiroNegocio] => 
                    [IdentificadorInstalacao] => 7008000000
                    [Ani] => 21981737137
                    [DataInicio] => 04/05/2021
                    [HoraInicio] => 10:36:21
                    [DataFim] => 04/05/2021
                    [HoraFim] => 10:37:31
                    [Dnis] => 
                    [MenuAtend] => 
                    [DocCliente] => 
                    [EnderecoVocalizado] => 
                    [Protocolo] => 
                    [GuidProtocolo] => 
                    [IdentificacaoNotaServico] => 
                    [Funcionalidade] => 
                    [Descricao] => 
                    [Usuario] => 
                    [NsDetails] => 
                    [created] => 04/05/2021 10:34:43
                )

        )

)
```

I have 4 arrays inside the array **response**. 0, 1, 2 and 3. in this example the 3 is the newest according to **DataFim** and **HoraFim**, but the data can come random. so I needed to know how to get the last array according to **DataFim** and **HoraFim**.

Any ideas on how to do this?

If performing the query directly with the json result is better, I accept suggestions.

Comment: Use `usort` and write your custom date comparison function.

Comment: You could sort the array and then pick the first/last element, depending on the direction of the order (newest-to-oldest or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

You need a select query using group by DataFim and HoraFim and order by desc limit 1 , like this you can select the most new array

Example of a query using group by and order by desc

```
"Select * from table_club Group by DateFim , HoraFim Order By DateFim,HoraFim Desc limit 1"
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: using this query in PHP solves the problem , the result of the query must give the most new array

Comment: in this case you need a filter method that filters by DateFim and HoraFim

Comment: sorry i was trying to help

Comment: Sorry is not a SQL, the reult came in json.it is a rest api that I consult and return to me in json. This value in json is returned as follows: `{"response":[{"canalAtendimento":"URA","DataFim":"04\/05\/2021","HoraFim":"09:42:25",...},{"canalAtendimento":"URA",...}]}`
and i need to know which is the newest object to get the values from only the newest object.